# How to get drop down in navbar to work in bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, angular6

I can get the navbar to be visible, but the drop down menu in the navbar does not work -- when I click on the drop down menu it does not display the menu.

I got the source code from another Bootstrap website. But it is not working properly in my project.

HTML:

```html
<nav class="mb-1 navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark info-color" style="background-color: #293631; height: 2cm">

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent-4"
      aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent-4" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent-4">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/madhusanka.edirimanna">
            <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i> Facebook
            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i> Instagram</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink-4" data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fas fa-user" ></i> Profile </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-info" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink-4">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My account</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/home">Log out</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/madhusanka.edirimanna">
            <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i> Facebook
            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i> Instagram</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink-4" data-toggle="dropdown"
             aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fas fa-user" ></i> Profile </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-info" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink-4">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My account</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/home">Log out</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

First check if you have used the links properly. A suggestion to you is using jQuery.min CDN not the slim version that is provided on Bootstrap. I have faced lots of problems for that. Also to keep the button right aligned I gave `.ml-auto` on the `button`. If you want it to be left aligned simply remove the class. Hope it'll help